# For loop for two variables in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Say I am running a regression in MATLAB and I want to use a for loop to say first do it for y1 and second do it for y2. Is this possible.

I am trying to think of a minimal example, the only this I can come up with to display what I am trying to do is here:

```
for ii = 1:10
      yt = z(ii);
end
```

Obviously it not running as I am far away from the right logic here , but basically I want to do something in MATLAB for y1 and then so again for y2 and y3 and so on. y1, y2 etc are arrays.

Is there any for loop I can use for zz(ii) to get z1 z2 z3.....

Comment: Provide a sample example with *actual matrices*

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide a simple example. Suppose you have a matrix `A` with an unknown amount of columns and rows and you want to iterate through all of them.

```
for i=1:length(A(:,1))
    for j=1:length(A(1,:))
        yt = A(i,j);
        % And what ever you want to do
    end
end
```

This way you can access each element individually.